# Cypress clicks on ellipsis but does not open popover

Tags: kendo-grid, cypress, ui-automation

Issue - The click on the ellipsis on the table opens a small pop-over, Cypress clicks on the element but does not open the popover. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**The Application: Vue Kendo grid**

[image]

**Cypress Run**

[image]

```html
    <td 
     data-v-cdc7d78e="">
     <div data-v-cdc7d78e="" 
          class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
          <svg data-v-cdc7d78e="" 
               xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-icon="ellipsis-vertical" 
               data-prefix="fas" 
               aria-hidden="true" 
               focusable="false" 
               role="img" 
               viewBox="0 0 128 512" 
               class="svg-inline--fa fa-ellipsis-vertical snapshot-menu-button" 
               id="snapshot-menu-button-101">
               <path fill="currentColor" 
                     d="M128 64c0-35.39-28.62-64-64-64S0 28.61 0 64s28.62 64 64 64S128 99.39 128 64zM128 256c0-35.39-28.62-64-64-64S0 220.6 0 256s28.62 64 64 64S128 291.4 128 256zM128 448c0-35.39-28.62-64-64-64s-64 28.61-64 64s28.62 64 64 64S128 483.4 128 448z">
               </path>
          </svg>
          <!---->
        </div>
    </td>
```

**The Popover - after clicking ellipsis**

```html
    <div
      id="snapshot-menu"
      role="tooltip"
      tabindex="-1" 
      data-v-cdc7d78e class="popover b-popover-left dropdown-popover"
      x-placement="left"
      style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; transform:translate3d(!009px, 371px,0px);"
    <div>
```

**Things I have tried**

```js
cy.get('#snapshot-menu-button-4').invoke('attr', 'focusable', 'true').click({force: true})
```

```js
cy.get('[aria-rowindex="70"]').trigger('focus').then(() => {
    cy.get('#snapshot-menu-button-4').click({force: true});
})
```

```js
cy.get('[aria-rowindex="70"]').click().then(() => {
    cy.get('#snapshot-menu-button-4').click({force: true});
});
```

```js
cy.get('[aria-rowindex="70"]').trigger('mouseover').then(() => {
    cy.get('#snapshot-menu-button-4').click({force: true});
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo Vue Grid has a cell property that allows custom templating. Depending on how the Vue template is built, you may need to investigate the issue further. If using bootstrap, the issue may be [the popover element](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/popover#triggers). By default, the popover is triggered by a click event. However, if you set the triggers attribute, you override the default functionality. [So you will need to add 'click' to the triggers attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVwHj.png)

Answer (score 2):

The id `#snapshot-menu-button-4` is on the `<svg>` which may not have the click handler.

Try either parent element

```js
cy.get('#snapshot-menu-button-4')
  .parent()
  .click()

// or

cy.get('#snapshot-menu-button-4')
  .parents('td')
  .click()
```

Comment: Thank You @Fody for responding. I did try both but Cypress says it has clicked the element but does not show the popover.